# Deconvolution with unknown impulse response

Tags: filters, convolution, impulse-response, deconvolution, blind-deconvolution

*This is not a duplicate of [Filter secondary bounces of a pulse signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93392/filter-secondary-bounces-of-a-pulse-signal) because in that question, a convolution model is finally not appropriate, whereas here, the question is about convolution*.

---

Given the signal `y` below, is there a way to recover the original signal `x` (before convolution), *without knowing the impulse response `h`*?

Of course, additional hypotheses are required to avoid having an infinity of solutions. In the example below, we could reasonably assume that:

- a) `x` is just one Gaussian
- b) or, weaker assumption: `x` has only one local maximum (for the case `x` is a bell curve, but not Gaussian)
- c) or another possibility: `h[i] != 0` only if `i = 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, ...` (reasonable here by looking at the `y` plot and the period of the bounces)

**Can we conclude with an algorithmic solution, in one of these 3 cases?**

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
x = np.zeros(200)
x[:50] = norm.pdf(np.linspace(-5, 5, 50))
h = np.zeros(120)
h[0] = 1
h[20] = 0.2
h[40] = 0.1
h[60] = 0.05
h[80] = 0.02
h[100] = 0.01
y = np.convolve(x, h)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152304/discussion-on-question-by-g6kxjv1ozn-deconvolution-with-unknown-impulse-response); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter secondary bounces of a pulse signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93392/filter-secondary-bounces-of-a-pulse-signal)

Comment: What if it is just a simple IIR?

Answer (score 3):

> What methods are there for such deconvolution problems,

None for the general case (without additional information). We can easily see this by looking at the frequency domain

$$y(t) = h(t)*x(t) \leftrightarrow Y(\omega) = H(\omega) \cdot X(\omega) $$

This is equivalent the the question "I know that $a\cdot b = 23.78$ what are $a$ and $b$?" There is an infinite amount of possible solutions.

> and which additional assumptions would be needed to get a solution

There is no general answer here either. You can always try some heuristics but how far that gets you will depend a lot in your specific.

In your example you could probably squint at the signal and identify "this looks like a repeated Gaussian with a decay on the repeats". But there are infinite ways to generate the same output. A few examples

1. One Gaussian with a six tap sparse FIR
2. A once repeated Gaussian with a three tap FIR
3. A twice repeated Gaussian with a two tap FIR
4. The output signal as is with a unit impulse FIR

You have no way of telling which one it is, so you need some way to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for stating what I've been trying to explain so nicely + kindly! +1. I'll add that your 1-4 are results of models (or models themselves), just for OP to reconcile my terminology with yours.

Comment: Thank you Hilmar. Yes of course, there is an infinity of solutions, I totally agree with your examples, The question is: are there any "reasonable" assumptions that allow us to conclude? Example: would there be an algorithmic solution if we assume that a) `x` is just one Gaussian, how would you do in this case?   b) weaker assumption `x` has only one local maximum?

Comment: I edited the question @Hilmar to make the necessity of these assumptions clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you raised is called [Blind Deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_deconvolution).

In the general case indeed it is an ill posed problem.
Yet with a strong prior (Model for the signals / filters) you can get a good results.

If you model the signal as a linear combination of shifted Gaussians it can be solved iteratively (Though not globally) by solving 2 sub problems:

1. Given `h` estimate `x`.
2. Given `x` estimate `h`.

You can solve them for different `k` where `k` is the number of combinations.
The problem for `x` will be non convex problem as we need to estimate the shifts.

You may have a look at a similar problem very well known in the field of Image Processing: [How to Solve Blind Image Deblurring with Total Variation (TV) Prior Using ADMM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75664).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Royi. More precisely, would you have a method in mind, in a few steps, for the example signal of my question, if we assume `x` is just one gaussian? Then I'll try to turn it into an algorithm and I'll post it.

Comment: @g6kxjv1ozn, If it is a single Gaussian and unknown filter then the parameters of the problem are: Kernel, Shift, Scale. Just build the problem is least squares and solve for each parameter iteratively assuming the other 2 are known: Kernel -> Deconvolution, Shift -> Matched Filter, Scaling -> Single Variable LS.